# Docker Desktop UI does not show the actually running containers anymore since a recent update

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

Eversince a recent Docker update Docker desktop refuses to show anything useful in its GUI - any ideas how to fix this? Do I need to roll back to an old version? And yes, I did try to close and open the GUI to refresh ...

[image]

Could this be due to I am using Windows subsystem for Linux?

Here is my version info

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.12
 Version:           20.10.5
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        55c4c88
 Built:             Tue Mar  2 20:14:53 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:15:47 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4
  GitCommit:        05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc93
  GitCommit:        12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue on docker for windows [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9401).